# Some problem with `hepthesis` document class

Tags: errors, thesis, hepthesis

Why, when I use `hepthesis` document class, do I get some error like this:

> Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup \end{figure}

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. ... That being said, it seems like not all of your opening braces are matched with closing braces, or perhaps not all of your `\begin{environment}`s are matched with `\end{environment}`s. Check to make sure.

Comment: Is the problem you're experiencing specific to the `hepthesis` document class, or does it continue to occur if you use a document class such as `report` or `book`?

Comment: no.. it just occur on hepthesis documentclass

Comment: If that's the case, then a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is likely going to be needed for anyone to be able to (easily) help you.